# How to place a copy of T* at a given address?

Tags: c++

Consider a type `T` and a pointer to `T`, `T*`.

Is there a way to place a copy of `T*` at a given address `x`, without using `memcpy()` and in a portable way?

Edit:

Just to be clear, I don't want to construct `T` at address `x`. I want to copy the value of the pointer to `T`, `T*`, at address `x`, as in

```
char* p = new char[s];
memcpy(&p[0], t, sizeof(T*)); // t is T*
```

Comment: A copy of `T*`? What does it mean? A copy of the pointer? Or a copy of the pointed object? If you need a copy of the object, why are you talking about a copy of the `T*`?

Comment: Sure: `T * original; T * copy = original;`

Comment: Perhaps you could talk with code instead of with English, to make it clearer what you'd like to do.

Comment: copy a type with assignment (`operator=`) is just like that: `a=b;`. Note that pointers as builtin types have assignment.

Answer (score 3):

**If you want to construct an object at a specific address**, you use placement-new:

```
#include <new>

T oldT = /* .. */;
T* newT = new (x) T(oldT); // copy-constructed at address x
```

It's just like `new T()`, except you specify the buffer. (So take care that it's aligned and lives long enough.)

---

**If you want to copy a value pointed to by a pointer**, just dereference the pointer:

```
T* x = /* .. */;
T copyT = *x; // dereference x, make copy
```

---

In both cases, replace `T` with your type (be that `U` or `U*`, etc.).

Comment: T* newT = new (x) T(); is not what I want. I don't want to construct T at address x. I want to copy T* at address x.

Comment: @Martin: Refresh the page, I've edited. To be fair: (1) your goal is a bit unclear, as AndreyT notes, and (2) it shouldn't be difficult at all to extrapolate how to make a copy.

Comment: Don't forget to destroy with `newT->~T();`.

Comment: @Gman It's not what I want. I have edited to make my question more clear with an example using memcpy()

Comment: @Martin: My first example shows what you want: `new (&p[0]) T*(t)`. What are you using this for? It almost looks like you want a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* all you're asking for is this:

```
void **address = ...; // address points to a location which can store a void*
T *t = ...;
// note T* and void* are the same size 
// now any of these three should work:
static_cast<T*&>(*address) = t;
*reinterpret_cast<T**>(address) = t;
void *t_addr = t;
*address = t_addr;
```

Comment: Note that the casting in this answer is only okay because the type we're dealing with is POD. In the general case, use placement new, which handles all types correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had to use it before, but it looks like 'placement new' might be useful in solving your problem.

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10

Answer (score 0):

```
T *& newVal = new (x) T**(oldVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void* X;
typeT* T;

X=x;
* (typeT*) X = *T;
```

This should be portable.
Note however that enough space must appropriately allocated before the copy (=) operation takes place.